# Local variables goes missing

Tags: java

I face a strange error.  During the startup of the server, i initialize a set of variables in the init() method of a java class.  I could see this value is persisted during the server startup.  However, when i try to login through the WebUI, these local variables goes missing.

However, if i assign the variable in a static block, it stays on.

I dont know how this could happen.  Any pointers would help.

Java version : **JRE1.7.0_40**

My piece of code looks like

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA { public static String testString;  public static
  void init() throws Exception   {
  testString = "testSTring222";   } }
```

ClassB.java

```
ClassA.init(); System.out.println(ClassA.testString)
```

Please help me get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly depends on what does your server.

Use some static variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Class A**

```
public class ClassA
{
    public static String testString = "testSTring222";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class ClassB
{
    static ClassA cA = new ClassA();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(cA.testString);
    }
}
```

So you should reference `Class A` as a static class and make the and set the static string when you first declare it as a variable

Answer (score 0):

This could happen due to the usage of multiple class loaders, since `static` variables are not global across multiple class loaders. i.e. if the same class is loaded in 2 different class loaders, then you will have 2 copies of the static variable.